# Displaying Bootstrap 4 navbar collapse only on XS screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

According to [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/) this is the display utility to show/visible an element ONLY on xs screen:

[image]

Now at following example I am trying to hide the `.collapse` in all screens except of `xs` by adding the `d-block d-sm-none` to the

```
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-block d-sm-none" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

but this is not only hiding the collapse in the SM, MD, and LG screens but it is only hiding the `.collapse` in XS screens! As you can see clicking on the drop down button not sliding down any `.collapse`

My code is below. Why is this not working when applying to the `.collapse` element?

```css
.d-none {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-block d-sm-none" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: A quick reminder that you should not put the word "issue" or the word "question" in your title - they are all issues and questions. The latter is stopped by the editor, but as you have found, not the former. It is still pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the navbar css specifications instead of worrying about the collapse and display properties.

```
.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}
```

"Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` with `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` for responsive collapsing and color scheme classes."

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/